# How to deploy applications to the Smartwatch2 simulator

Tags: sony, sony-smartwatch

How to deploy applications to the  simulator can give a the most simple demo is ok maybe just shows a picture

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the PDF called "How to use the smart extension APIs" in the Sony SDK Add-on documentation package available here:

http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/documentation/sony-add-on-sdk-documentation-kit/

In there is an emulator section which describes exactly how to deploy your SmartWatch2 extension on an emulator.

Comment: First of all thank you for your guidance, but I still have doubts, watch simulator installed on mobile phones, can realize and the bluetooth connection of the unit or the connection of others, I have not found the bluetooth on the simulator

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand your question, can you rephrase it?  But I can say that if you use the SW2 simulator either on the Android emulator (AVD) or a physical device you don't need any bluetooth connection since the connection is "virtual".  You only need to make a bluetooth connection if you are using an actual physical smartwatch.

Answer (score 0):

As I know as long you have installed Liveware™ you don't have to implement any method for bluetooth connection. The SmartWatch can be used if you have already installed Liveware™ / SmartConnect.

There is a demo application created from Sony and they gave the documentation also to explain the demo. However, there is another demo not made by Sony, you can take a look from this example application from this website:

http://xiangchen.me/blog/?p=2214

If you want to practice to get the application in Android phone and SmartWatch application connected, you can try to send a String from Smartphone to SmartWatch.

If you want to do that, what you can do:

1. Build application in Android phone that can store from textView and can send that string with intent.
2. By using the demo application for SmartWatch that I have mentioned above, you can combine it  with the application you have made. So there will be only 1 project but contained 2 packages.
3. You add information for SmartWatch in AndroidManifest.
4. You create another class in SmartWatch and it is for receive the intent. That class should extends from Broadcast Receiver.

   1. After you received the intent you can show it in SmartWatch controlExtension.

--Moreless this is the concept that I have mentioned:

In phone application, you can add:

```
String message;
EditText etMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message);
message= etMessage .getText().toString();
```

After that you create the intent:

```
Intent broadCastIntent = new Intent("SendMessage");
broadCastIntent.putExtra("MESSAGE",message);
sendBroadcast( broadCastIntent );
```

And call it in BroadcastReceiver (in SmartWatch's package):

```
public class myBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String message= intent.getStringExtra("MESSAGE");
            sampleExtension.messageSW = message;
}}
```

And then in your extension (class for UI's SmartWatch):

```
 btextView.setText(messageSW );
```

Don't forget to declare the intent and the receiver in AndroidManifest

Hope it helps you..